# Java OpenNLP version 1.5.3. Spanish models

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

I have a question concerning OpenNLP. I am looking for Spanish sentence detection and tokenization models that run with OpenNLP version 1.5.3. So far, I only found a pos tagging model that works with this version (https://github.com/utcompling/OpenNLP-Models/tree/master/models)

Additionally to the Spanish models, I need to use also English, French and Italian models in one java project. So far, I could find all models (sentence detection, tokenization and pos tagging) for every language, except for Spanish, for which I just found the pos tagging model. I don't want to switch to OpenNLP 1.4. (http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models.html) because I cannot find French and Italian models for that.

All the best and many thanks in advance,
Bina

Comment: I think those are maximum models you can find online. You can train your own models according to your requirement nonetheless