# Error loading openNLP Spanish model POS tagger in R

Tags: r, nlp, opennlp, pos-tagger

I am trying to run a POS tagger function for Spanish text using R's openNLP package. I previously run the same function using a model for English text, but it seems there is not an official model for Spanish POS tagging in the openNLP page (http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/)

I found a previous question that pointed to a Spanish POS tagging model ([Java OpenNLP version 1.5.3. Spanish models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959983/java-opennlp-version-1-5-3-spanish-models)), which I tried to use, but I got the following error message when I tried to use any of the models available there:

```
word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator(model = 'opennlp-es-perceptron-pos-es.bin')
```

However:

```
Error in .jnew("opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerModel", .jcast(.jnew("java.io.FileInputStream",  : 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException: The TokenizerME cannot load a model for the POSTaggerME!
```

I suppose that the binaries available in that github repo are not in the format that is expected by "Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator".

Do you know how I could solve this issue, or are you aware of any other Spanish POS tagging model that I can plug into my code?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.